# Group by in SQL Server and concatenate records in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, group-by

I have a view named `payment_data` that includes numeric, date and string fields.

```
company | ref | Tag | event_date | sale_price | Amount  |  Receipt_No  | Paid  |   Balance

PRco Ltd| 123 | 0311| 03-10-2018 |  610000    | 610000  |  R19A0000761 | 50000 |   11000
PRco Ltd| 123 | 0311| 03-10-2018 |  610000    | 610000  |  R19A0000912 | 11000 |    0
```

This table is to be grouped to get the following result

```
company | ref | Tag | event_date | sale_price | Amount  |  Receipt_No                |  Paid  |  Balance
PRco Ltd| 123 | 0311| 03-10-2018 |  610000    | 610000  |  R19A0000761, R19A0000912  | 61000  |    0
```

The table is grouped by column `ref` and the `Receipt_No` is concatenated to get as shown above. The column `paid` is aggregated and column `sale_price` and `Amount` should be the Max(). The column `balance` is balance amount to be paid. That should be 0 if the customer pays full amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You** can use `STUFF` and `GROUP BY` with `MIN,MAX,SUM` aggregation as below and in your example `paid amount is in 5 digit` and `amount in 6 digit` so it can't be `zero` in balance. In my example I made `6 digits paid amount` to match with your expected result but you should correct and use it as needed

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE(company VARCHAR(50), 
    ref INT, 
    Tag INT, 
    event_date DATE, 
    sale_price INT, 
    Amount  INT,  
    Receipt_No VARCHAR(50), 
    Paid INT, 
    Balance INT)

INSERT INTO @sales VALUES
('PRco Ltd',123,0311,'03-10-2018',610000,610000,'R19A0000761',500000,11000),
('PRco Ltd',123,0311,'03-10-2018',610000,610000,'R19A0000912',110000,0)

SELECT s.company, 
    s.ref, 
    s.Tag, 
    s.event_date,
    MAX(s.sale_price) sale_price,
    MAX(s.amount) amount,
    MAX(s1.receipt) receipt,
    SUM(s.paid) paid,
    (MAX(s.amount)-SUM(s.paid)) balance
FROM @sales s
OUTER APPLY (
            select stuff(
                (select ',' + s1.Receipt_No 
                from @sales s1
                where s1.company = s.company
                AND s1.ref = s.ref
                AND s1.Tag = s.Tag
                AND s1.event_date = s.event_date
                for xml path('')
                )
            , 1, 1, '') receipt
        ) s1
GROUP BY s.company, s.ref, s.Tag, s.event_date
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
company     ref Tag event_date  sale_price  amount  receipt                 paid    balance
PRco Ltd    123 311 2018-03-10  610000      610000  R19A0000761,R19A0000912 610000  0
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query help you to get the desired result. The sample table created for your reference, you can use the view as needed. Stuff function help to concatenate the receipt numbers

```
DECLARE @Payment_Data Table(
    Company VARCHAR(50), 
    Ref INT, 
    Tag INT, 
    Event_date DATE, 
    Sale_price INT, 
    Amount  INT,  
    Receipt_No VARCHAR(50), 
    Paid INT, 
    Balance INT)

INSERT INTO @Payment_Data  VALUES
('PRco Ltd',123,0311,'03-10-2018',610000,610000,'R19A0000761',500000,11000),
('PRco Ltd',123,0311,'03-10-2018',610000,610000,'R19A0000912',110000,0)


SELECT  Company, 
        Ref, 
        Tag, 
        max(Event_date), 
        max(Sale_price),
        MAX(Amount) amount,
        SUM(Paid) paid,
        (MAX(Amount)-SUM(Paid)) Balance,

        Receipt_No = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + Receipt_No
          FROM @Payment_Data  p2
          WHERE ref = p2.ref
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    FROM    @Payment_Data  p1
    GROUP BY Company, Ref, Tag
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It can use `GROUP BY` like following.

```
SELECT s1.company, 
       s1.ref, 
       s1.tag, 
       s1.event_date, 
       max(s1.sale_price)  sale_price, 
       max(s1.amount)  amount, 
       STUFF ((SELECT ', ' + CAST(receipt_no AS varchar(100))
                FROM 
                payment_data pd where pd.ref=s1.ref
                ORDER BY receipt_no
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,2,'' ) AS Receipt_No,
       sum(s1.paid) paid ,
       min(s1.balance) balance
from payment_data s1
group by company,ref,tag,event_date
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/XYJH26292)

Answer (score -2):

You can use group_concat function to concat based on Group by.

```
SELECT  company, ref, Tag, sale_price, Amount, 
    dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(Receipt_No + ',' ) AS Receipt_No , sum(Paid)
FROM    dbo.foo
GROUP BY company, ref, Tag, event_date, sale_price, Amount
```

Comment: Wrong database - this is sql-server